# laravel- undefined index id

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am failrly new to laravel and am building a simple app. I am using this function in my controller:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }


public function index()
{

    //
    //return view('adminlte::home');
    $user= Auth::user()->id;
    $csafe = csafe::where('username','=', $user->email)->get();
    return view('csaves.show', array('csafe' => $csafe));
}
```

thr table csaves has two rows of data with different ID (PK) for the user I am logged in with. 
but when I bring up the view in web browser I get the following error:

> Undefined index: id

in my view blade file I have:

```
      @foreach ($csafe->id as $id)
          <h1>csafe  {{ $id }}</h1>
      @endforeach
```

how could I show all the values of my array /table with the selected criteria in this view?

I would appreciate even if you could guide me how to put it in a grid or a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it like this

```
@foreach ($csafe as $c)
      <h1>csafe  {{ $c->id }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: did you dump `$csafe`? what it shows? check it with `dd($csafe)`

Comment: where should I put the dd($csafe)?

Comment: before `foreach` loop or in your controller(this one would be better)

Comment: I put it in both but nothing changed, or maybe I don't know where should I check the dump value

Comment: put it before `return` in your controller, `dd($csafe); return view('csaves.show...`

Comment: thanks, this is the result: Collection {#328 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => csafe {#329 ▶}
    1 => csafe {#330 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158230/discussion-between-skileton--and-user-12321).

Comment: Thanks for all th help in debugging this via chat. Appreciate it. The problem was all the commented lines in the view file which for some reasons were manipulating the behaviour of view.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one csafe so you shouldn't be using a foreach loop. Just use this:

```
<h1>csafe {{ $csafe->id }}</h1>
```

Comment: I removed the first(), part, I need all values in the array, I editted the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

first of all just, i want to know if the `user` has many `csafe` ? if yes  modify your index method like this

```
public function index()
{
    //
    //return view('adminlte::home');
    $user= Auth::user();
    $csafe = csafe::where('id','=', $user->id)->get();
    return view('csaves.show', compact('csafe'));
}
```

and inside your view

```
@foreach ($csafe as $c)
      <h1>csafe  {{ $c->id }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for reply, yes, a user has many csafe, and i also have tried the compact, but still same error persists.

Comment: so please replace your index method by my index method and if you can show me all columns table of csafe please !

Comment: ok just after this line      $csafe = csafe::where('id','=', $user->id)->get(); do dd($scafe) what show up ?

Comment: sorry , the id was basically username, but still, I added the dd(&csafe) and here is the results:{#328 ▼ #items: array:2 [▼ 0 => csafe {#329 ▶} 1 => csafe {#330 ▶} ] }

Comment: so for that you can not show some attribute if not exist please, just replace id by username in your view blade